# How to set up sshd so that it never asks for a password for a specific user?

Tags: linux, security, ssh, password, gitolite

I have a dedicated system account named "git" that is managed by gitlab/gitolite. Users connecting to this account always use SSH keys, "git" user doesn't have a password. If users connect without a SSH key or with a mis-configured key, they get confused by being asked for a password. I'm looking for a way how to set up the server so that in such a case it doesn't ask for a password and instead it displays some kind of user-friendly message ("Your key is missing or invalid" etc.) and drops the connection. Is it possible, either in sshd configuration, or in some other way (PAM perhaps)?

Note that I'm *not* asking how to set up public/private password-less connections. Just how to prevent the server asking for a password for a single specific user.

(I understand that such setup reveals to a potential attacker that user "git" exists in the system. But since "git" has no password and an attacker can easily determine its existence anyway, I consider it only a low risk.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable password logins for that specific user. You can't provide a specific message, but at least they won't be prompted for a password. Add the following in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Match user git
    PasswordAuthentication no
    ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

Comment: I had to remove `UsePAM no` because the server complained it's not allowed inside `Match`, but otherwise it does exactly what I wanted. Thanks.